# Mac Pro no longer shows "Headphones" in sound widget

Tags: audio, sound-volume, speakers

I have a 2013 Mac Pro (trashcan) running 12.6.8. I have a set of speakers plugged into the headphone port on the back. I've used this successfully for a decade.

Sometime in the recent past, I think when I installed .6.x, the "Headphone" option disappeared from the sound widget in the menu bar. Now it says "Line Out". The same is true in the Sound control panel.

Selecting Line Out does not play through the speakers.

Anyone know how to fix it?

[image]